# How to initial weights of neural network using FTRL optimizer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In logistic regression, the initial values of `n,z` can all be zeros, then updated by the gradient. However, same initialization can lead to zero predict in neural network, thus network can never be updated. So what is the reasonable initialization when train neural network using FTRL?

Comment: What do you mean by `n` and `z`?

Comment: The same as `http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2490000/2488200/p1222-mcmahan.pdf `